# How to restrict user rights on Debian?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, bash, unix

I have a production server, which runs an web application. Now I need to grant SSH access to a developer in order for him to work on the files of the application. He already has a chrooted sFTP access, but now circumstances require to expand this access to SSH.

Ideally the developer could only see it's home directory (this is not absolutely necessary) and the document root of the application (let's say `/var/www/html/app`).

Is there any way to achieve that result? I thought about a chrooted SSH, but it's quite extensive to configure that (I would need to create a `bin` directory and create links to all binaries he would be allowed to use). `rBash` is not a solution, because one could not `cd` what makes it too inconvenient.

How could I limit/restrict a certain UNIX user?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "UNIX" in your question?

Comment: @Paradox Sorry if it is unclear: I mean a system user, which has SSH access

Answer (score 1):

sudo mount --bind /var/www/html/app /home/user/folder

Give him access to be able to read and write in there. Job done.

Comment: for details see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount

Answer (score 0):

To restrict logins under (Debian/Linux) OpenSSH, disable `PasswordAuthentication` and enable `PubKeyAuthentication` in your (login server's) `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Then, for the user needing to access a shell, drop their OpenSSH pubkey into their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (on login server). Take care that the public key (*not* the private key!) is inserted into the file in one single line. There should be no line breaks. Sometimes this happens with `nano` when editing and won't be apparent. Also, make sure permissions are set on `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` as `user:user_group` and `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (on login server).  Directory permissions on their home directory is important as well (on login server). Monitor `/var/log/auth.log` (or equivalent) for login errors (on the login server) related to directory permissions or other. You can get more info into `auth.log` by changing `LogLevel` to VERBOSE in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Another method, (or second layer of security) is to use `/etc/security/access.conf` (on the login server) and define who can login from where as whom.  You will need to enable `pam_access` to achieve this, if it is not already enabled.